# How to store Integers from a string without using the getline function. C++

Tags: string, input, getline

Sorry to ask, but I been looking everywhere to find a way to extract the integers from this set of strings:

```
{(1,2),(1,5),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,4),(4,3),(4,5),(5,1),(5,4)}
```

I don't really need the homework done, if you could link me to an example, I'll appreciate it.
thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the *integers* from a line like that, one way is to simply continue reading integers while you can.

If, for some reason, you find an integer read failing (because there's a `{` in the input stream, for example), just skip over that single character and keep going.

Sample code for this is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int intVal;                              // for getting int
    char charVal;                            // for skipping chars
    while (true) {
        while (! (std::cin >> intVal)) {     // while no integer available
            std::cin.clear();                // clear fail bit and
            if (! (std::cin >> charVal)) {   //   skip the offending char.
                return 0;                    // if no char left, end of file.
            }
        }
        std::cout << intVal << '\n';         // print int and carry on
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A transcript follows:

```
pax> echo '{(314159,271828),(42,-1)}' | ./testprog
314159
271828
42
-1
```

Comment: That is just awesome!! I'm playing with it to make fit my code since I have to translated into matrix!! thank you, Thank you so much, I had no idea you could something like (! (std::cin >> intVal)) to test whether it is an integer or a char!
Again! Thank you!!